# application crashing due to null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading, nullpointerexception, datagram

I have created the instance of other class in send class and called the function of other class from the send class but it gives NPE . My send class from where I called the function of other class ,which is broadcast class and also this function is called when the button is clicked.

```
  broadcast broadcastobject.threadfunc(messages);
```

My class where I create threads is:

```
  public class broadcast  {

private DatagramSocket socket;
String str;
private static final int TIMEOUT_MS = 10;
WifiManager mWifi;
EditText et;
DatagramPacket packet;
Button bt;
private static final int SERVERPORT = 11111;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.255";


public void threadfunc(String message){
    str=message;
                new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

/*
 private InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() throws IOException {
        DhcpInfo dhcp = mWifi.getDhcpInfo();
        if (dhcp == null) {
          //Log.d(TAG, "Could not get dhcp info");
          return null;
        }

        int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
        byte[] quads = new byte[4];
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
          quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);
        return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
      }

      */

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {


        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT);

            socket.setBroadcast(true);
    //              socket.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT_MS);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            InetAddress serverAddr = null;
            try {


                serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);


            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           packet = new DatagramPacket(str.getBytes(), str.length(),serverAddr,SERVERPORT);

            try {

                    socket.send(packet);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    } 

    }

}
```

My send.java is:

```
public class Send extends android.app.ListFragment  {

WifiManager mwifi; 
Button bt1;
boolean testwifi;
TextView tv1;
EditText et1;
String str1;
int id=1;
String messages;
private DataSource datasource;
broadcast broadcastobject;

void wifi() {
    mwifi=(WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);


    if(!mwifi.isWifiEnabled())
    {
        if(mwifi.getWifiState()!=WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED)
            mwifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send, container, false);
    datasource = new DataSource(getActivity());
    datasource.open();

    List<Message> values = datasource.getAllMessages();

    // Use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
    // elements in a ListView
    ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Message>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
   setListAdapter(adapter);

    bt1=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv1=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    et1=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Message>) getListAdapter();
                Message message = null;

            /*  ConnectivityManager cn= (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cn.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI); 
    testwifi=networkInfo.isConnected();
    if(!testwifi)
        tv1.setText("wifi is off");
    else
        tv1.setText("wifi is on");*/



                wifi();



                // Save the Data in Database
                messages=et1.getText().toString();

                // check if any of the fields are vaccant
                if(messages.equals(""))
                {
                                           Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                }
                else
                {

                     message = datasource.createMessage(messages);
                      adapter.add(message);

                // broadcastobject=new broadcast(messages);
                //broadcastobject.start();

                      broadcastobject.threadfunc(messages);

                      et1.setText("");
                }



                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });



    return rootView;


}
/*public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

{

loc.getLatitude();

loc.getLongitude();
String Text = "My location is: " +

"Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() +

"Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();

//finish();


Toast.makeText( getActivity().getApplicationContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText(getActivity(). getApplicationContext(),"GPS Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

}


public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"GPS Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}



@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

     }*/
@Override
public void onResume() {
    datasource.open();
    super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
public void onPause() {
    datasource.close();
    super.onPause();
  }


    }
```

My log cat is:

```
09-01 17:35:50.350: D/gralloc_goldfish(3557): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
 09-01 17:36:10.300: D/AndroidRuntime(3557): Shutting down VM
09-01 17:36:10.309: W/dalvikvm(3557): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
 09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557): java.lang.NullPointerException
  09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):   at soft.b.peopleassist.Send$1.onClick(Send.java:114)
  09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
  09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
 09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
 09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
 09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-01 17:36:10.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   09-01 17:36:13.150: I/Process(3557): Sending signal. PID: 3557 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Where is `Send.java`? The exception is thrown in that class.

Comment: check my edited question i've added send class in the question it is the class from where i am calling the function .

Comment: Where is the line 114 in send.java point that out too in the code block using comment.

Comment: broadcastobject.threadfunc(messages);

Comment: @AmeerHumXa Instead of `if(messages.equals(""))` have a check there that `if((messages==null) || (messages.equals("")))` . Chekc for the null condition as well.

Comment: still not working ,same error, @ShobhitPuri

Comment: That's because you haven't created any object of class `broadcast` and are calling the function directly. First you need to create an object. Since the function is not static you cannot use it without using an object of that class.  Before using it something you need to create object lilke : `broadcast broadcastobject = new broadcast();`

Comment: @ShobhitPuri broadcastobject is the object of broadcast class and i have defined it globally.

Comment: Do you feel that there is there a difference between defining and creating an object ? Can you please refer to me where in the code are you creating an object ?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri thanks you were absolutely right ,its now working ok for one or two time.but after that I press the button and the instance is created again and function is called ,its again crashing.

Comment: This might be because each time you'll click a new object will be created. You can declare the function inside `broadcast` class as `static` and access it as `broadcastobject .functionName(...)`.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri shall i create the instance every time the event is called or for once in the code?

Comment: @AmeerHumXa Once I guess.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri i have created the instance in onCreate for once instead of making the function static and now its working absolutely fine, Put it in answer so i can mark it as answer, thanks alot man,

Comment: Glad to help Ameer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving `null` pointer because you haven't created any object of class `broadcast` and are trying to call the function present in that class. Since the function is not static you cannot use it without using an object of that class. So, first you need to create an object before calling the function like:

```
broadcast broadcastobject = new broadcast();
```

Comment: i've one more little problem in broadcasting the packet in broadcast class, would you help me?

Comment: Sure. If I know I'll love to help. Although for a different problem, its good to post a different question. Other can have a look as well. Do post the link here once you post the new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556332/message-only-received-once-on-the-server-on-android-app

Comment: check if you can help :)

Comment: @AmeerHumXa Sorry, I read it but couldn't contribute. since I don't have much experience with that.