# Message only received once on the server on android app

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, datagram

I have a server app and client app running separately on different android devices and am broadcasting the message in LAN from client app and server is listening but the problem is that the message is only received once at server, My client code is:

```
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
             str = et.getText().toString();
                new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
        }
    });



}

/*
 private InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() throws IOException {
        DhcpInfo dhcp = mWifi.getDhcpInfo();
        if (dhcp == null) {
          //Log.d(TAG, "Could not get dhcp info");
          return null;
        }

        int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
        byte[] quads = new byte[4];
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
          quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);
        return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
      }

        */

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {


        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT);

            socket.setBroadcast(true);
           //               socket.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT_MS);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            InetAddress serverAddr = null;
            try {


                serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);


            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

      packet = new DatagramPacket(str.getBytes(), str.length(),serverAddr,SERVERPORT);

            try {

                    socket.send(packet);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    } 

    }

}
```

My server class is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Boolean shouldRestartSocketListen=true;
TextView tv1;
//MulticastLock lock;
static String UDP_BROADCAST = "UDPBroadcast";
DatagramSocket socket=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


startListenForUDPBroadcast();

}


private void listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(InetAddress broadcastIP, Integer port) throws Exception {
    byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];
//  if (socket == null || socket.isClosed()) {

        //socket.setBroadcast(true);
//  }
    //socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
    while(true)
    {
    socket = new DatagramSocket(port, broadcastIP);
    Log.e("UDP", "Waiting for UDP broadcast");
    socket.receive(packet);

//  String senderIP = packet.getAddress().getHostAddress();
    String message = new String(packet.getData()).trim();

//  Log.e("UDP", "Got UDB broadcast from " + senderIP + ", message: " + message);
    tv1.setText(message);
    }
    //  broadcastIntent(senderIP, message);
//  socket.close();

}
private void broadcastIntent(String senderIP, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.UDP_BROADCAST);
    intent.putExtra("sender", senderIP);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
   Thread UDPBroadcastThread;

void startListenForUDPBroadcast() {
    UDPBroadcastThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress broadcastIP =           InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.255"); //172.16.238.42 //192.168.1.255
                Integer port = 11111;
                while (shouldRestartSocketListen) {
                    listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(broadcastIP, port);
                }
                //if (!shouldListenForUDPBroadcast) throw new ThreadDeath();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("UDP", "no longer listening for UDP  broadcasts cause of error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    UDPBroadcastThread.start();
}



void stopListen() {
    shouldRestartSocketListen = false;
    socket.close();
}

public void onCreate() {

};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopListen();
}



public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line `tv1.setText()` inside `listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent()`. Only the UI thread can touch views. If you need to set the tv1.setText() you need to do it in the UI thread, there are several methods for doing this, look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Comment: what about the client class is it ok to send multiple messages?

Comment: in client every time i press the button new thread is created and new udp socket and packet will be created using the same ports and server address, is it right to do this? because my server only receive once and set text on tv1 just once.

Comment: Server receives just once because it makes an error by touching the view (tv1). Client can send as many packets as it wishes. What you mean by server address, don't you send in broadcast?

Comment: yeah am broadcasting the message. How to use runOnUiThread instead of textview?

Comment: No, you don't use `runOnUiThread` instead of the `textview` what it means is that you need to `runOnUiThread` to set the `textView.setText()`. In other words, in order to touch a view of an activity (main UI) you need to execute your code in the UI thread.